# failed when using str_replace

Tags: php

i am new in PHP, i am trying to delete a post with an image, before delete the image in the storage drive, I have to change the image path from http://localhost/Twitter/Post/52/POST-1F3D1ABB-D525-4107-BE08-B5F8B7B5E29B.jpeg to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Twitter/Post/52/POST-1F3D1ABB-D525-4107-BE08-B5F8B7B5E29B.jpeg"

thats why I use `str_repalace` to change the imagePath,but i got the error

> Notice: Undefined variable: path in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/twitter/post.php on line 123
>
> Warning: unlink(): No such file or directory in
>
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/twitter/post.php on line 126
>
> **{"message":"successfully deleted","result":1,"status":"Image has been
>   failed to be deleted from drive"}**

i got undefined path variable in this line

```
$path = str_replace("http://localhost/", "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/", $path);
```

what went wrong in here ?

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST["uuid"]) && empty($_REQUEST["id"])) {


    $uuid = htmlentities(strtolower(stripcslashes($_REQUEST["uuid"])));
    $imagePath = htmlentities(($_REQUEST["imagePath"]));


    $result = $access -> deletePost($uuid);

    if (!empty($result)) {

        $returnArray = [
        "message" => "successfully deleted",
        "result" => $result
    ];



    if (!empty($imagePath)) {


        $path = str_replace("http://localhost/", "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/", $path);


        if (unlink($path)) {
            $returnArray["status"] = "Image has been deleted from drive";
        } else {
            $returnArray["status"] = "Image has been failed to be deleted from drive";
        }



    }


    } else {

        $returnArray = [
        "message" => "Couldn't delete the post"
    ];

    }





}
```

Comment: $path is not defined as the error states. I think you may mean $imagePath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line:

```
$path = str_replace("http://localhost/", "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/", $path);
```

Should be (switch `$path` for `$imagePath`)

```
$path = str_replace(
    "http://localhost/", 
    "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/", 
    $imagePath
);
```

**But** using `http://localhost/` and replacing with `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/` makes it 100% not portable, it will break once you move the code somewhere else.

Instead you should use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to grab the path, and as `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/` simply looks like a path to your webroot, forget about using it.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://localhost/Twitter/Post/52/POST-1F3D1ABB-D525-4107-BE08-B5F8B7B5E29B.jpeg';

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

echo $path; //Twitter/Post/52/POST-1F3D1ABB-D525-4107-BE08-B5F8B7B5E29B.jpeg
```

Then just use `unlink($path);` it should work fine and it makes your code portable.